# Missing characters in SCNText (iOS 14)

Tags: ios, arkit, ios14, scntext

The following code (iOS, ARKit project) creates a **SCNText** node and attaches it to the root node of the ARKit scene:

```
let font: UIFont = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: fontSize, weight: UIFont.Weight.regular)
let attributes: [NSAttributedString.Key : Any]? = [NSAttributedString.Key.font: font]
let text = NSAttributedString(string: "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz:123456789", attributes: attributes)

let textGeometry = SCNText(string: test, extrusionDepth: 0.1)
let textNode = SCNNode(geometry: textGeometry)
rootNode.addChildNode(textNode)
```

When I run it in either simulator or device with iOS 14, I get a text with missing some characters (e.g. "a", "e", "y"):

[image: Sample output from SCNText]

It works fine when I use regular **String** as an input param of **SCNText** but does not work with **NSAttributedString** + **system font** (the font matters). It works fine in the previous iOS (iOS 13).

Have you met a similar issue with missing characters? Have you found any workaround?

The sample Xcode project showing this issue can be found [here](https://github.com/pleszkiewicz/SCNTextDemo).

Comment: I am also having the same issue. Tried monospacedSystemFonts and that worked fine. But I would want to use system font.

Comment: @KushalJogi Using e.g. UIFont(name: ".SFUIText", ...) seems to work fine but I would also like to use system font :)
Btw UIFont(name: "HelveticaNeue", ...) also works fine, but UIFont(name: "HelveticaNeue-Bold", ...) does not work. Really strange.